# How to split every other element from a huge column of list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7, data-science

I have a huge list in python in a single column and i need to split all the fruits, colours etc  from the list and make a dafaframe.

```
example
details=['banana', 
'type:', 
'fruit', 
'color:', 
'yellow', 
'orange', 
'type:', 
'fruit', 
'color:', 
'orange',
'blueberry', 
'type:', 
'fruit', 
'color:', 
'blue']
```

what I'm expecting to achieve is if I  extract all color from above then the result should be a single column of list like below.

```
Out[1]:

['yellow',
 'orange',
 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract only colors, you can use the package `colour` - https://github.com/vaab/colour

```
In [7]: from colour import Color

In [8]: details
Out[8]:
['banana',
 'type:',
 'fruit',
 'color:',
 'yellow',
 'orange',
 'type:',
 'fruit',
 'color:',
 'orange',
 'blueberry',
 'type:',
 'fruit',
 'color:',
 'blue']

In [9]: colors_only = set()

In [10]: for i in details:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         Color(i)
    ...:         colors_only.add(i)
    ...:     except: pass
    ...:

In [11]: colors_only
Out[11]: {'yellow', 'orange', 'blue'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
details=['banana',
         'type:',
         'fruit',
         'color:',
         'yellow',
         'orange',
         'type:',
         'fruit',
         'color:',
         'orange',
         'blueberry',
         'type:',
         'fruit',
         'color:',
        'blue']
# split each fruit as a list and index colors 
details = [details[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(details),5)]
fruits = []
color = []
for i in details:
  fruits.append(i[0])
  color.append(i[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach **if** the data-structure doesn't change, is using list comprehension:

eg: `[details[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'color:']`

**Full code:**

```
details=['banana',
'type:',
'fruit',
'color:',
'yellow',
'orange',
'type:',
'fruit',
'color:',
'orange',
'blueberry',
'type:',
'fruit',
'color:',
'blue']

colors = [details[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'color:']
fruits = [details[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'type:']
types = [details[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'type:']

print('fruits: ', fruits)
print('types: ', types)
print('colors: ', colors)
```

**Output:**

```
fruits:  ['banana', 'orange', 'blueberry']
types:  ['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit']
colors:  ['yellow', 'orange', 'blue']
```

**Or as Dataframe**

```
# to make datafame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['fruits'] = [details[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'type:']
df['types'] = [details[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'type:']
df['colors'] = [details[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(details) if x == 'color:']

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      fruits  types  colors
0     banana  fruit  yellow
1     orange  fruit  orange
2  blueberry  fruit    blue
```

**Explanation:**

1. value of colour comes after the string `color`, so find the indices of that string in the list
2. add **1** to this index to get the value of color
3. use this with list comprehension to get desired output array
4. repeat for other values